# Tensorflow federated prediction after the model is trained

Tags: prediction, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am new to Tensorflow federated and have trained a tff model. I want to use this model to predict on unseen data. Google colab has been used for this. I tried using the trainer object but it says 'AttributeError: 'LearningProcess' object has no attribute 'predict''. Went through the official documentation but couldn't find a solution.

Here's my code:

```
def model_fn():
    fl_model = create_keras_model() **#this function creates a tf neural network**
    return tff.learning.models.from_keras_model(
        fl_model,
        input_spec=input_spec(),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[ tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()]
        )

trainer = tff.learning.algorithms.build_unweighted_fed_avg(
    model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.02),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1.0)
)

train_state = trainer.initialize()

train_hist = []
for i in range(EPOCHS):
    result = trainer.next(train_state, train_data)
    train_state = result.state
    train_metrics = result.metrics
    train_hist.append(train_metrics)
    print(f"\rRun {i+1}/{EPOCHS}", end="")

# Giving input according to the label encoded dataset
params = np.array([1,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,0,-1])
params = params.reshape(1, -1)

# Making a prediction using tff FL model
prediction = trainer.predict(train_state.model, (params, np.array([[0]])))

# Printing the prediction
print(f"Prediction: {prediction}")
```

> It shows 'AttributeError: 'LearningProcess' object has no attribute 'predict'' in prediction = trainer.predict(train_state.model, (params, np.array([[0]])))